# PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank set at run time

Tags: acumatica

Screen: AR303000 Version/Build 19.104.0024

I need to set the Attention, Data Field, Properties to
PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank during runtime.

Logic: When CustomerClassID = 2 the Attention field has to change to required.
       ElseIF the CustomerClassID<>2 then the field is set to not required.
       ( this should be calculated during runtime and as it loaded)

I have tried using:

```
 PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<Contact.attention>(cache, row, PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank); 
 PXUIFieldAttribute.SetRequired<Contact.attention>(cache, true);
```

Hier is my current code:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
  public class CustomerMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
  {
 protected void Customer_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {      
      var row = (Customer)e.Row;
      CustomerClassID =row.CustomerClassID;
      if (row.CustomerClassID == "02")
      {
         //throw new PXException("Test if you hit this code at runtime");           
         PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<Contact.attention>(cache, row, PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank); 
      }
      else 
      {
        PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<Contact.attention>(cache, row, PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank); 
      }    
    }
}
}
```

/// I have also tried to override the attribute on-screen level:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
  public class CustomerMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
  {
    [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Attention")]
    [PXMassMergableField]
    [PXMassUpdatableField]
    [PXPersonalDataField]
    [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<Customer.customerClassID, Greater<decimal_1>>))]
    protected virtual void Contact_Attention_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    { }
}}
```

This is the first time I have to change properties at run time so I don't know what I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a cache attached event to attach a default/required set to the attribute. You have to merge the attributes, and follow the selector from the Contact to the BAccount. It will then compare it to a constant that was created. This code worked in my demo environment, all in the CustomerMaint graph.

```
//create constant class to check the CustomerClassID that is a string
public const string AttentionRequiredCustomerClass = "2";
public class attentionRequiredCustomerClass : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<attentionRequiredCustomerClass>
{
    public attentionRequiredCustomerClass() : base(AttentionRequiredCustomerClass) {; }
}

//////merge the attribute with the existing, setting the making Attention required when CustomerClassID = 2
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
//selector follows the contact's baccount to get the customer class, and compares it to the bql constant created above.
[PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<Selector<Contact.bAccountID, Customer.customerClassID>, Equal<attentionRequiredCustomerClass>>))]
protected virtual void Contact_Attention_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{ }
```

Comment: How would you change the statement to if class 02 and class 03 changes it to required?

Comment: I am sorry for the delayed response. I would add one class for each required, and then add an Or. For example: [PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<Selector<Contact.bAccountID, Customer.customerClassID>, Equal<attentionRequiredCustomerClass2>, Or<Selector<Contact.bAccountID, Customer.customerClassID>, Equal<attentionRequiredCustomerClass3>>>))]